# Maven error: Missing dependency 'java.lang.object' required by scala

Tags: scala, maven, dependencies

I don't know what exactly happened, but since today I am struggling to build the maven package I got an error I am struggling with.

When running:

```
mvn package
```

or

```
mvn install
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.4. Compiling...
error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', 
required by /.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar(scala/package.class)

error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', 
required by /.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar(scala/runtime/package.class)

error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
```

I have checked and the folder exists.

I have renamed the folder 2.10.4 and re-downloaded the dependencies from maven to get them new.

I still run in to this error and I don't know why or what to do, any suggestion?

Comment: Since, you have not provided any information about your project, I can begin with the only guessable reason. I think you are not using compatible JDK version. If you look at https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html, you will see that every Java version has a minimum scala version for compatibility. Since you are failing to compile for scala 2.10.4, I am guessing that you are using JDK version 9 or above.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh You are right, I was somehow I installed another jdk version or and it was providing the error, this is not a problem anymore, now I have another ones but thank you very much! Make a formal reply instead of a comment and I'll assign it to you as solved if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason my java version upgraded and was not compatible with the scala version I used.